# iText7 GetTextFromPage function

Tags: itext7

i'm trying to use  GetTextFromPage function in iText7 library, but it's not working
This is the code

thank you!

```
         PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pathPdf);
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);


            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Paragraph header = new Paragraph("PDF Page " + i.ToString());
                header.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                header.SetFontSize(20);
                document.Add(header);

                // New page
                document.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
            }

            PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(1);

            // Get content ----> ERROR
            string content = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);


            pdfDoc.Close();
```

I expect to retrieve the text of my pdf

Comment: When you create new content in a PDF, that content as soon as possible is written to the `PdfWriter` and removed from memory. If you want to parse the PDF you created, close the `PdfDocument` and read the result file into a new `PdfDocument`.

Comment: so to recap, pages cannot be accessed while creating the pdf. The only method is to close the pdf and reopen it.
thanks so much